# pdb: how to show the current line, instead of continuing after the previous listing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pdb

when using pdb to debug a python script, repeating `l` command will continue listing the source code right after the previous listing.

> `l(ist) [ﬁrst[, last]]` List source code for the current ﬁle. Without
>   arguments, list 11 lines around the current line or continue the
>   previous listing. With one argument, list 11 lines around at that
>   line. With two arguments, list the given range; if the second argument
>   is less than the ﬁrst, it is interpreted as a count.

How can I repeatedly show the current line (i.e. the line where the program running is paused), instead of continuing after the previous listing? Thanks.

Comment: Give the current line as single argument? You can know it using `w`.

Answer (score 4):

The direct way, of course, is to pass the line as an argument to `l`.

But without having to go through the trouble of finding the current line and typing it, the non-optimal way I usually do it is to return to the same line by navigating up+down the call stack, then listing again. The sequence of commands for that is: `u` (up), `d` (down), `l`.